# Retrieve List from Object with JPQL

Tags: java, jpql

I want to retrieve `proposalInsuredPersonList` from `lifeProposal` Object .But i got this exception `proposal.ProposalInsuredPerson cannot be
 cast to java.util.List`. Let me know how can i retrieve `List` .

```
            query.append("SELECT f.id, f.submittedDate, f.proposalNo, f.customer, f.organization, pi.proposedPremium, pi.proposedSumInsured, s.date, " +
                    "f.agent, f.proposalInsuredPersonList FROM LifeProposal f,LifeSurvey s INNER JOIN f.proposalInsuredPersonList pi where f.id = s.lifeProposal.id and f.id is not null");

            objectList = q.getResultList();
            for(Object[] b : objectList) {
                porposalId = (String) b[0];
                proposalDate = (Date) b[1];
                porposalNo = (String) b[2];
                if(b[4] == null) {
                    Customer c = (Customer) b [3];
                    customerName =  c.getFullName();
                    customerAddress =   c.getFullAddress();
                    fatherName = c.getFatherName();
                    phNo = c.getContentInfo() == null ? "" : c.getContentInfo().getPhone() ;
                } else {
                    Organization org = (Organization) b[4];
                    customerName = org.getName();
                    customerAddress = org.getFullAddress();
                    fatherName = null;
                    phNo = org.getContentInfo() == null ? "" : org.getContentInfo().getPhone() ;
                }
                inspectionDate = (Date) b[7];
                premium = (Double) b[5];
                sumInsured = (Double) b[6];
                if(b[8] == null) {
                    agentName = "";
                    agentNo = "";
                } else {
                    Agent a = (Agent) b[8];
                    agentName = a.getName();
                    agentNo = a.getCodeNo();
                }
                insuredPersonList = (List<ProposalInsuredPerson>)  b[9];
```

Comment: Well it seems as if you do not have a 'List<ProposalInsuredPerson>' but a 'ProposalInsuredPerson' in 'b[9]'.

Comment: @Matthias ,i dont want to get ProposalInsuredPerson . I want only list. Thanks

Comment: And I want ice cream, but your resultset is returning a single object and not a list there. If you want a list then add this item to a new list, should not be that hard.

Comment: You can't select a list.

Comment: Side note: "query" is obviously StringBuilder or StrigBuffer. So use it as it meant to be used instead of string concatenation with "+"

Comment: How did you map "proposalInsuredPersonList" in LifeProposal (@OneToMany)?

Comment: @mrak @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "lifeProposal", orphanRemoval = true)               private List<ProposalInsuredPerson> proposalInsuredPersonList;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer as far as I can, based on the code you show here.
You loop over your resultset and at index 9 of the returned objects you receive a `ProposalInsuredPerson` object.
Since you want the whole list, I recommend adding this object to a `List` implementation (`ArrayList` comes to mind) which is declared and instantiated outside of your for loop.

So something like that will fix your problem:

List insuredPersonList = new ArrayList();

```
for () {
// your code here

// ...
  insuredPersonList.add((ProposalInsuredPerson) b[9]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rewriting your query like this:

```
query.append("SELECT f.id, f.submittedDate, f.proposalNo, f.customer, f.organization, pi.proposedPremium, pi.proposedSumInsured, s.date, " +
                    "f.agent, f FROM LifeProposal f,LifeSurvey s INNER JOIN f.proposalInsuredPersonList pi where f.id = s.lifeProposal.id and f.id is not null");
```

i.e. replacing `f.proposalInsuredPersonList` with whole `f`

and the on the last line do this:

```
insuredPersonList = ((LifeProposal) b[9]).getProposalInsuredPersonList();
```